# Django not uploading image files to Azure storage container

Tags: python, django, azure, sqlite

**How do I link my Azure blob storage to my Django admin, such that it uploads the file *to* the blob storage account when saving a new record.**

I have my image upload set up in the admin already. The admin interface acts like the image is attached before I click save, although I am aware that the image file is not actually stored *in* my SQLite3 database.

I can reference them successfully in the consumer-facing portion of my project when the images are **manually** uploaded to the Azure blob storage account. I don't want to manually upload them each time, for obvious reasons.

There has to be a simple solution for this, I just haven't had success in researching it. Thanks in advance!

models.py

```
class Image(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.file 

class Product(models.Model):
...
    picture = models.ManyToManyField(Image)
...
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media').replace('\\', '/')

MEDIA_URL = 'https://my_site.blob.core.windows.net/'
```

Using Django 1.7, Python 2.7, SQLite3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django-storages has support for an Azure blob backend which would allow any uploads you do to be automatically stored in your storage container.

http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/azure.html

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the solution I needed!

Comment: Just kidding, it keeps uploading the file as application/octet-stream

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built-in Django API that allows us to change the blob's content type. But from my experience, you can use Azure SDK for Python to upload blobs: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python. The most important setting in your case is the content type. By default content type is application/octet-stream. However you can change it via x_ms_blob_content_type. Please refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/ for a sample and feel free to let us know if you have any further concerns.

Answer (score -1):

My Configuration

```
# Media
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/<user>/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Remember  folder need permission (write, read) apache user
example:

```
<img src="/media/img/my_image.png">
```

or

```
<img src="{{obj.file.url}}">
```